# Is there an easier way to get the current time in hh:mm:ss format?

Tags: c++

I tried to print the current time in the usual format of hh:mm:ss however I get the full date format instead. I need the answer to be in string or int, so it is easier to deal with. I was thinking of adding it to a log file so that I can make it easier to track my program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>    

int main()
{
    auto curr_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::time_t pcurr_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(curr_time);
    std::cout << "current time" << std::ctime(&pcurr_time)<<"\n";
}
```

I do want a little tip to help me do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following example displays the time in the "HH:MM:SS" format (requires at least c++11 - tested with clang):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    std::time_t t = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
    std::tm ltime;
    localtime_r(&t, &ltime);
    std::cout << std::put_time(&ltime, "%H:%M:%S") << '\n';
}
```

Compiling and running:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11 so.cpp
$ ./a.out
13:44:23
$
```

Comment: can you please explain it to me? I am still new to c++ and don't get ctime and chrono well.

Comment: `std::chrono` is a utility library from the C++ standard allowing for time manipulation. In particular you may obtain a current time. There are various clocks available there, but here you are using system clock which is a wall clock exposed to time adjustments, i.e. it does not always monotonically increases. More info about std::chrono you may find [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono).

Comment: Based on the current time taken from chrono you may obtain a time_t value which usually indicates amount of seconds elapsed since [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). See more [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time)

Comment: The `std::tm` structure represents a calendar time (so time_t but broken down into year/month/day + hour/minute/sec. localtime_r converts such epoch time to you local calendar time (so that depends on your system settings). See [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/tm) and [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/localtime)

Comment: The std::put_time converts the calendar time to an out-streamable character string according to the specified format ("%H:%M:%S"). More info [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time)

Answer (score 8):

Using `std::chrono` and `std::format`:

- You can just pass a `time_point` and format it according to a [format specification](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/local_t/formatter). In the example below `%T` is equivalent to `%H:%M:%S` (hours in 24-hour clock, and minutes and seconds using 2 digits).
- If you don't want to print out microseconds, you can `floor` the current time.

Note `std::format` requires C++20.

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>  // cout

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    namespace ch = std::chrono;
    std::cout << std::format("{:%T}", ch::floor<ch::seconds>(ch::system_clock::now()));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

if you need only current time

```
auto now = system_clock::now();
std::cout << std::format("{:%T}", now);
```

and if you need localtime

```
const std::chrono::zoned_time cur_time{ std::chrono::current_zone(),
                                    std::chrono::system_clock::now() };
std::cout << std::format("{:%T}", cur_time) << '\n';
```

in c++23

```
std::print("{:%T}", system_clock::now());//or chrono::zoned_time
```

⚠Warning for Windows⚠

> Time-zone data is only available for Windows 10 version 1903/19H1 and later, and Windows Server 2022 and later.
> [Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/zoned-time-class?view=msvc-170)

Comment: Is there a C++23 chrono way for Windows pre-2022 (without using zoned time)?

Comment: @Molochnik 
this warning is only for use of zoned_time. The first block of code works

Comment: Nope, the first part doesn't work either (I've got a customer with 2012 Server) which I test remotely, if my DLL uses anything that contains "zone" in its name it fails to load completely.